# How to fix Index problem for firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have my rules for the index, but I am still getting this following error when data is large.

The Error is @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "time" at /history/bearhistory to your security rules for better performance.

```
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
        "bearhistory": {
      ".indexOn": ["time"]
    },
      "history": {
      ".indexOn": ["time"]
    }

  }

}
```

As I said, it works when I work with minimum limitToLast.

```
this.items = this.db.list(`history/bearhistory`, ref => ref.orderByChild("time").limitToLast(10000));
```

When data limitToLast is bigger, I am getting these error for the index. I have this data structure.

[image: Data Set]

How can I fix the error to work on the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, the query is running on `/history/bearhistory`, so that is where you need to define the index:

```
"rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true,
   "history": {
      ".indexOn": ["time"],
      "bearhistory": {
        ".indexOn": ["time"]
      }
  }
}
```